# Json object value by concatenating two variables

Tags: json, concatenation

I am trying to create a json which contains a key value pair where the value is generated based on a concatenation of another two variables(strings).

Apart from concatenating like,

var a = "A";
var b = "B";
var c = a+" "+b;


and using variable 'c' directly, is there a way to append variables within the key value as below.

```
var fName = "Test1";
var lName = "Test2";

var json = {"fname":fname,"lname":lName,"fullname":"'fName'+' '+'lname'"}
```

I expect to result {"fname":"Test1","lname":"Test2","fullname":"Test1 Test2"}

Please let me know if this is possible to achieve.

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
var fName = "Test1";
var lName = "Test2";

var json = {"fname":fName,"lname":lName,"fullname": fName + " " + lName}
```

**Edit:** Following the comments, I'll illustrate other ways to play with JSON strings and objects...

```
// json is a JavaScript Object
typeof json  // -> "object"

// If you want to create JSON string representing it, use JSON.stringify()
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json)

typeof jsonString  // -> "string"

// If you like pain, you can also build that string manually
// with the right escape sequences... (Do not do that)
var sillyJsonString = "{\"fname\":" + "\""+fName + "\",\"lname\":" + "\"" + lName + "\",\"fullname\":" + "\""+fName + " " + lName + "\"}"

typeof sillyJsonString  // -> "string"

// And now let's make sure they have the same content
jsonString === sillyJsonString  // -> true

// And the final part, re-create the object for JSON string
var sameJsonObject = JSON.parse(sillyJsonString)

// Now let's compare that the objects have the same content (but the are not equal ;))
JSON.stringify(json) === JSON.stringify(sameJsonObject)  // -> true
```

Hope this will point you in the right direction...

Comment: I am passing effective json within double quotes as below.

```
"{"fname":fName,"lname":lName,"fullname": fName + " " + lName}"
```

Any escape character or any method to use this

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to parse some JSON? Create a JSON string? If you parse it, where do you take it from? What are these "triple single quote"?

Comment: Triple quotes added to format the code in comment. Ignore that please,

Thank you for the clarification. I am trying to update json on the fly. Seems it's not possible. So I will create a new variable with merged values. Thanks for your support Antony.

Comment: What do you mean by on the fly? If json is an object, not a string (like in your original question), you can add properties to it: json["newKey"] = "newValue"

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Json is a string in this case. It's a hassle and I am considering a different approach. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Manipulating the string directly can be done but it's a hassle, and the approach you take depends a lot of what your json is and how you want to change it... A parse / update / stringify should be a better approach unless your string is huge... Anyway, if you agree that the original question has been answered, please accept this answer or add more details.